# How to escape insecure content in form in order to prevent XSS?

Tags: php, html, forms, escaping, xss

I know that it might stupid but **how to escape user input when I show it in a form**. I do not mean any output, but especially in the form inputs. Like for example if I have input tag and put the user text in the value.

```
<input type="text" value="'test' "test" <script>alert('hacked');</script>" />
```

When I leave it like that it appears correctly

```
'test' "test" <script>alert('hacked');</script>
```

no XSS happens, but I do not feel secure cause with other code it could break eventually. Is there something like a browser build-in methods for preventing XSS when putting data in the form or I am missing something?

Edit: I did not say the entire story. Sorry about that. When I use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` I get the escaped data which I do not want. I see this in the input, which is not what was entered :(

```
'test' &quot;test&quot; &lt;script&gt;alert('hacked');&lt;/script&gt;
```

I want to prevent XSS and to show the content without changing it at the same time. Is it possible in this case.[image]

Comment: You **definitely** don't want to handle this in the client side (the webbrowser) which the enduser has full control over. You should be handling this fully in the server side. As to how to do it depends on the programming language used which you didn't mention in the question. Please update your question as such.

Comment: @BalusC if previous questions are any indication my guess is PHP

Comment: I now how to escape html, the thing is that when it is in the input value the output does not look as the input. I want to prevent XSS, but the end user to be able to see and eventually edit the same text that was entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should HTML encode the text, so that it ends up like this:

```
<input type="text" value="'test' &quot;test&quot; &lt;script&gt;alert('hacked');&lt;/script&gt;" />
```

You should use the server language to do this. There is no built in support for this in Javascript, so you would have to build a function for that yourself.

In ASP.NET MVC for example it could look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(Model.UserInput) %>" />
```

MVC 2 also has the `<%: %>` tag that automatically encodes the text:

```
<input type="text" value="<%: Model.UserInput %>" />
```

#### Edit:

Examine the source of the page in the browser to see what the result is.

It looks like you are escaping the text twice, so that for example `"` is escaped into `&quot;` and then into `&amp;quot;`.

Comment: But I want the end user to be able to see and edit the original content, not the one that was escaped. I want ot be able to see the <script> and change it in the input while still protected from XSS.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev: You HTML code the value so that it will be interpreted correctly by the browser. The value that is shown in the input will be the original string.

Comment: Is this without escaping or with escaping? I have attached an image to show the output that I get, which is the reason for my question in SO. If I escape I get non sense, if I do not I am afraid of XSS.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev: Examine the source of the page in the browser to see what the result is. It looks like you are escaping the text twice, so that for example `"` is escaped into `&quot;` and then into `&amp;quot;`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I was wondering what is goind on and why escaping is weird. I was escaping data twice. Add this in your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape XSS characters in any GET or POST content (for example, if your data is called `$_POST['data']`, escape that like this: `$variable = htmlspecialchars($_POST['data']);`). Also, if you're using a database use `addslashes()` to escape quotes and apostrophes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How are you putting the user text?  If you have control, from the server side all    languages support encoding the output prior to rendering it on the browser.

As long as you sanitize the output.  You can basically allow the user to enter anything that they wish.  Then when displaying the content, you just need to encode it so that the browser will not execute it.  This can be done from any language PHP, JScript, ASP, VB, C#, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since the quote mark is used to break out of the input attribute, simply replace all quote marks with &quot;

Comment: How about a textarea? Should I look for a </textarea or something else and escape it also in order to prevent XSS.

Comment: It looks like textarea tags will take the full escaping with &lt, &gt, &quot, etc.